# What are these coordinates on $\mathbb S^n$ called?

Tags: differential-geometry, terminology

I vaguely remember some special kind of coordinates on the sphere $\mathbb S^n$ as a Riemannian manifold, but I have forgotten their name: They are defined by choosing a great $\mathbb S^{n-1}$ and considering the geodesic from every point of it, that travels in the direction orthogonal to the $\mathbb S^{n-1}$. The distance of a point on this geodesic to the $\mathbb S^{n-1}$ defines the first entry of the coordinate tuple. The other entries are given by some coordinate system on $\mathbb S^{n-1}$.

I must admit, that I only vaguely remember these coordinates and might be slightly mistaken about their definition. The metric of $\mathbb S^n$ at least should be in the form $dt^2+ g(t)(x)$ where $t$ is the geodesic distance to $\mathbb S^{n-1}$.

There should be such coordinates at least in a neighborhood of every point on the $\mathbb S^{n-1}$. I now would like to know, what the name of these coordinates is and (if you can tell me) also what the metric $g(t)$ is in these coordinates. I would appreciate every answer to this question.

Comment: Unless you mean [(hyper)spherical coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperspherical_coordinates#Spherical_coordinates), could you describe how you want these coordinates to differ from those?

Answer (score 2):

I think you are talking about [normal coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_coordinates). Sometimes it is also called geodesic normal coordinates. The metric has the form $dt^2+ g(t)(x)$, look at the section "polar coordinates" of the above link.

Comment: I am not totally sure, if I mean notmal coordinates. As far as I remember the value of $t$ was not the distance to a specific point but to a great $S^{n-1}$.